# most concise way to create a scatterplot with regularly spaced color bands around the identity line

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am comparing two tools to measure the same thing, and to have a nice way of conveying how they do (or do not) agree with each other I want to use scatterplots with regularly spaced color bands around the identity line, green for points between ± 1, light red for ± 5, dark red for ± 10, something like in this plot. [image]

To do so, I came up with this rather cumbersome code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
ax = plt.gca()
measure_1 = np.random.normal(loc = 75, scale = 10, size = 200)
measure_2 = measure_1 + np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 2, size = 200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.vstack((measure_1, measure_2)).T,\
                  columns = ["V1", "V2"])
sns.scatterplot(ax = ax,\
                    x = df['V1'],\
                    y = df['V2'],\
                    alpha = .5)
ax.plot(np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
            df['V1'].max(), num = 1000),\
            np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
            df['V1'].max(), num = 1000))
ax.fill_between(np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
    df['V1'].max(), num = 1000),
    np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
    df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) + 1,
    np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
    df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) - 1,\
    color = 'green',\
    alpha = .3)
ax.fill_between(np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000),
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) + 5,
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) + 1,\
   color = 'indianred',\
   alpha = .3)
ax.fill_between(np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000),
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) - 1,
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) - 5,\
   color = 'indianred',\
   alpha = .3)
ax.fill_between(np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000),
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) + 10,
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) + 5,\
   color = 'maroon',\
   alpha = .3)
ax.fill_between(np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000),
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) -5,
   np.linspace(df['V1'].min(),\
   df['V1'].max(), num = 1000) - 10,\
   color = 'maroon',\
   alpha = .3)
```

It's long, it's ugly and it is not easy to reuse. I am sure that there must be a more concise way of doing it, maybe with `pyplot.pcolormesh`, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Suggestion unrelated to the main question here: if you want to compare two outputs like this, you should use the same axes limits (ideally with square axes, or set `aspect="equal"`) and it can be helpful to add a diagonal constant line.

Comment: Also you could clean up your `fill_between` code a lot by defining the `linspace` grid once and assigning it to a variable. And you don't need to use backslash (`\`) to continue a logical line within a function call.

Comment: @mwaskom: the identity line is plotted just after the scatterplot. You're right about defining the `linspace` just one, it will clearly clean up the code. As for the backslash, thanks, I really thought it was needed for each new line !